# Transform a DOMDocument into a DOMNode

Tags: php, dom

I might be missing something obvious, but how do you turn a `DOMDocument` into a `DOMNode`, in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

A `DOMDocument` already **is** a `DOMNode` ([see documentation](http://php.net/domdocument)):

```
 DOMDocument extends DOMNode
```

It represents the root node as well as the document itself.

Comment: Sure, but how do you typecast it to `DOMNode`? (I want to handle it like any node)

Comment: I guess my question is: how do I create a `DOMNode` from a string of an HTML fragment?

Comment: @julien_c - What if the fragment is `<p>foo</p><p>bar</p>`? You'd need *2* nodes :-?

Comment: There is no typecasting of objects in PHP but it is not necessary, because the dynamic type system. So, you already *can* handle it like any node. Your comment "how do I create a DOMNode from a string of an HTML fragment?" confuses me, this seems lika a totally different question.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario No, you can constrain that the input string represents a single node.

Comment: @fab You're right, here you are: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14839879/593036 (though they are related)