# Create a DOMNode from a string of an HTML fragment

Tags: php, dom

How can I create a `DOMNode` from a string of an HTML fragment, assuming of course the string contains a single root node?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createdocumentfragment.php

Comment: @MarcB This doesn't let one create a node from markup though, does it?

Comment: no. but once you've got the fragment, you can AppendChild to insert it into the dom.

Comment: @MarcB Ok sure, but how do you create it from a **string of markup** (this is what the question is about)

Comment: like you would with any other chunk of html. docfrags are basically just full domdocuments that happen to exist independently inside a dom tree. it has a loadHTML() method.

Comment: @MarcB That's actually incorrect. `DOMDocumentFragments` **do not** have a `loadHTML()` method.

Answer (score 3):

**DOMDocumentFragments** do have a **loadXML()** method

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(1);

$opts = array('http' => array('header' => 'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1, *;q=0'));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$html = file_get_contents( 'http://multiple.webcindario.com/wstest.php' , false , $context );

$html = html_entity_decode(htmlentities($html, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'), ENT_QUOTES , 'ISO-8859-1');
ob_clean();
$classname = "product";
$domdocument = new DOMDocument();
$domdocument->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
$domdocument->formatOutput       = false;
$domdocument->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($domdocument);
$found = $xpath->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classname ')]");

$newHTML="<div class='foo bar'><p>This is <b>an <i>example</i></b> paragraph    <a href='#!'>#!</a></p></div>";
$newHTML = html_entity_decode(htmlentities($newHTML, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'), ENT_QUOTES , 'ISO-8859-1');

foreach($found as $oldnode){
   $frag = $domdocument->createDocumentFragment();
   $frag->appendXML($newHTML);
   $oldnode->appendChild($frag);
   $updatedHTML=$domdocument->saveHTML();
 }
```

ex: https://fernando.requeixo.com/addNodefromHTML.php

(this adds an example paragraph as a chilNode to the selected Nodes of the source)

Comment: I would suggest to clean up the example code a bit, so it is easier to see the relevant parts. As it stands, there is a lot of unrelated code to understand before you get to the  actual fragment example.